# Helm fails on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, kubernetes-helm

I installed Helm (the package manager for Kubernetes) on Windows 10 pro through Chocolatey.

When I am trying to execute `helm` command on the command prompt (running as Administrator), I am seeing a prompt saying "this app can't run on pc". Closing the prompt is showing "Access Denied" on the command prompt.

I also tried downloading the zip from Helm's website and create a System environment variable under Path.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the resolution here.
I am able to resolve it by deleting the helm folder under `C:\program files` and reinstalling helm using Scoop. Chocolatey may also help here to install helm.

P.S. Scoop and Chocolatey are package managers for Windows. Just like Homebrew is for macOS